# only pandas scatter plot - scale color bar when is binary

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to plot very simple data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.randint(1,1000, n),
              "y": np.random.randint(1,1000, n),
              "z": pd.Categorical(np.random.choice([1,0], n))})

data.plot(x="x", y="y", kind="scatter", c="z")
```

However, it always ends with a colorbar when `z` is integer/numerical (and binary) or categorical;

[image]

I have found plenty of solution for this, but only using non-pandas packages. I'm looking for a **only-pandas package** solution. And if it's possible, with `1 = green`, `0 = red`.

**EDIT:**

Given the answers of this post, it's to my understanding that pandas doesn't allow to access the colorbar. Hence, This is solved using any matplotlib solution.

Comment: `..."z": pd.Categorical(np.random.choice(["red", "green"]...`?

Comment: @Mr.T the colors needs to be red green for those respecive values.

Comment: Pandas uses matplotlib for plotting, and there is no predefined binary colormap in matplotlib. You have to retreat to matplotlib as shown by Quang Hoang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
# define custom color map
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
cmap = ListedColormap([[1,0,0], [0,1,0]])

# use plt.scatter for color bar customization
plt.scatter(data.x, data.y, c=data.z, cmap=cmap)

# force the ticks
cb = plt.colorbar(ticks=[0.25,.75])
cb.set_ticklabels([0,1])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But.. you are using matplotlib. I need to use only pandas.

Comment: I don't think pandas allows you to access the colorbar. It uses matplotlib backend anyway. Or you can use seaborn.

Comment: I don't get the "only-pandas" restriction. Pandas uses matplotlib, so if you have pandas installed, you also can access matplotlib.

Comment: Actually, it was just for simplicity. But given that pandas doesn't allow to access to the colorbar, it doesn't makes sense the restricion, so I will use matplotlib.@QuangHoang can you explain how can I edit the intensity of red/color you put there? or maybe giving an alternative for colors? I thought it was RGB code numbers but `ListedColorMap()` only allows `[0,1]` range values.

Comment: @Chris yes, that's exactly RGB `[1,0,0]` is for red, `[0,1,0]` is for green. You can also use `['red','green']`, but it's would be different green. [`ListedColorMap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap) also takes RGBA color.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks! But I still don't understand something. If it's RGB, why it cant take values between 2 and 256? (which are the range of RGB colors)

Comment: there are two common conventions, RGB can be integers between 0 and 255 or floats between 0 and 1. Matplotlib chooses the later. Most of the digital formats use the former. However, 10-bit colors are emerging as well (0 to 2**10-1).